# How to insert "import" line automatically

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In my previous Android project I could just click alt-Enter to insert 
appropriate "import" line.
Now it does not work.
I am tired to google import lines for each added Android class.
Thanks,

Comment: which IDE are you talking about?

Comment: Have you checked that Settings->Editor->Auto Import has all the fields checked? Have you tried invalidating caches and restarting the IDE? This is not normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to automatically organize imports

"Settings -> Editor -> Auto Import"

Comment: "auto import" in Settings is enabled. As I said, it does not work. After alt-Enter a pop up menu appears with two choices: "create class", "create inner class".

Comment: @nms - in that case you have been excluding important information from your question. This means that whatever you are trying to import is either not on the classpath or not in a source folder recognized by the IDE. Is the class you are trying to import a system class or something you have defined yourself?

Comment: For example I can't add "import" for class "Time".

Comment: you mean android.text.format.Time? Are you using Gradle to manage the project? If yes, have you tried to run clean and rebuild? Also, have you tried invalidating caches and restarting as suggested earlier (File->Invalidate...)?

Comment: chrsva, after File->Invalidate alt-enter starts to insert "import". Thanks!

Comment: No probs, glad you got it working :)